# Fosuser Bundle modifies user on login

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a strange issue using FosUserBundle with Symfony 3.1. On each login, the salt of the user is modified and the enabled field is set to false, making it impossible to login again whitout modifying the database.
my configuration is standard:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: UserBundle\Entity\User
```

Need help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I recall correctly, the only thing that FOSUser does on login is update the `lastlogin` field. What do _you_ do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It may help ...
I had temporarly put a comment around my callback function

```
/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
*/
/*public function(){
...}*/
```

Doctrine hates that ... a priori. Set it empty instead.
regards